# Micro USB devices compliance for dock stations

Tags: usb, usb-device, plug

Are there standards to define the micro USB plug front or back side to be compliance with dock stations ?

Usually dock stations are designed to have a micro USB plug pointing up, and the plug is positioned with its larger and flat side to back, and the beveled borders side to front. So, several devices can be plugged on these docks and keep its front side to front, and the bottom side to bottom, seems to be obvious, but it is not.

Unfortunately, some devices has the micro USB port positioned in others places, like in the sides either in the top. And the supposed front and back sides of the plug doesn't overlap with the device.

The Nexus 6 (Motorola) has a micro usb port in the bottom, but when connected to dock stations its display is oddly positioned to back. But there're worst others devices with the micro usb port positioned in the upper-left corner of the device.

So, the front and back sides of the plug adopted by dock stations designers, are just a convention or a standard ?

Why Nexus 6 has the micro USB port rotated 180 degrees compared to most smartphones ?
[image]

Comment: Whomever down voted and close voted, op is asking about electronics manufacturing standards, wtf is your problem.

Comment: The Moto Razr family is on the side the USB plug.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall seeing anything in the USB standard for this, orientation to user. Typically it's logo/bevel edge up/towards user. And beveled edge tends to be the one away from the pcb it's surface mounted on.